# calling a command through python 3 "shell"

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, environment

ok. so i have a startup script that i run with "python -i /home/josh/pysh.py" from .bashrc so i can run a term and it goes straight to python and runs my script. this is so i can make a command line environment like bash but in python(i didnt care for ipython).

i've been doing this but it doesnt always work in some cases.
the variable would be a list if there are args.

```
from subprocess import call
nano = 'clear'
```

then at the shell i can type:

```
call(clear)
```

how can i make it so i can just type:

```
clear
```

also if possible id like to embed some of these in seperate modules to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is simple.

```
from subprocess import call
def clear():
     call("clear")
clear()
```

Just copy the file to /usr/lib/python3.4/clear.py

chmod a+x /usr/lib/python3.4/clear.py
and run 
import clear

Comment: 1: does the clear() at the bottom go in the file or just called from the shell? and 2: i did that and got <Module 'clear' from /path/to/clear.py>

Comment: im on python 3.6 if its any different

Comment: ok so that works if i type it directly in the shell but not if i import a module with it

Comment: im on python 3.4